# Bitmarket.pl API translate from PHP to Python

Tags: php, python, api, translation, url-encoding

I have serious problem with changing PHP sample code to equivalent in python. 
Here is an example PHP code:

```
function bitmarket_api($method, $params = array())

{
    $key = "klucz_jawny";
    $secret = "klucz_tajny";

    $params["method"] = $method;
    $params["tonce"] = time();

    $post = http_build_query($params, "", "&");
    $sign = hash_hmac("sha512", $post, $secret);
    $headers = array(
        "API-Key: " . $key,
        "API-Hash: " . $sign,
    );

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.bitmarket.pl/api2/");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $ret = curl_exec($curl);

    return json_decode($ret);
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

UPDATE:

My code is:

```
apiurl = "https://www.bitmarket.pl/api2/"
key = "mypubkey"
secret = "myceretkey"

apicommand = "info"
tonce = time.time()

params = str(apicommand) + " " + str(tonce)

postdata = (params + " " + "&")

signdata = hmac.new(postdata, secret, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()

headerapi = { "API-Key: ": key, 
"API-Hash: " : signdata}



getapi = requests.post(apiurl, data=headerapi ,params=postdata)
print getapi.text
```

Result: {"error":501,"errorMsg":"Invalid API key","time":1486049060}

Comment: Yesterday I've spend few hours trying to send correct request via python requests and urllib2 now i've deleted whole code because it was NOT working at all. Every request was finished with wrong auth message. If someone just could let me know how should post data look like. I don't know PHP so it's hard for me to figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried Google: "Post data with python"?

Comment: Yep , I think I'ts all about im sending just wrong data.
    apiurl = "https://www.bitmarket.pl/api2/"
    apidata = hmac.new("info", secret_key_here, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
    getapi = requests.post(apiurl, data=apidata)

Comment: So give it a shot again and if you get stuck, come back and show us what you've tried (update your question with the code, don't post code in comments) and we can help you from there. Right now, you're basically asking us to do your job for you...

Comment: I gave already , Im just suck in this form yesterday and now im fighting with it since 7 AM ... If i just knew what is result of that php code. Thanks anyway for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

```
def mergeTwoDicts(x, y):
    z = x.copy()
    z.update(y)
    return z


def bitMarketPlApiCall(method, params = {}):
    postDataAsDict = mergeTwoDicts(params, {
        'method': method,
        'tonce': int(time.time())
    })
    postParamsAsString = "&".join([param + '=' +     str(postDataAsDict[param]) for param in postDataAsDict])

    postHeaders = {
        'API-Key': publicKey,
        'API-Hash': hmac.new(secretKey, postParamsAsString, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
}

    request_response = requests.post('https://www.bitmarket.pl/api2/', data = postParamsAsString, headers = postHeaders)

    return request_response.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

[Curl issue in subprocess Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618777/curl-issue-in-subprocess-python/41619275?noredirect=1#comment70466714_41619275)

I point out exactly what you are asking for, other then for someone to translate PHP to Python for you (this should get you about 90% of the way there.)